# Defining and calling function at the same time in lua

Tags: javascript, lua, closures

In javascript, one can quickly create closures by defining and calling a function at the same time like this:

```
function() {
    local something = 1;
    return function () {
        // something
    }
}()
```

Is it possible to do the same in `lua`?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same way: `(function(x) print(x*x) end)(5)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can create immediately invoked function expressions (IIFEs) in Lua. Lua requires parentheses around the function expression: `(function () return 10 end)()`. Remove the parentheses, `function () return 10 end()`, and you get a syntax error. And naming the function is impossible: `(function f() return 10 end)()`. The named function syntax is syntactic sugar for assigning the function to a variable, `f = function() return 10 end`, and assignments are not expressions in Lua so they cannot be called as functions.

[JavaScript](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/01/13/disassembling-javascripts-iife-syntax) requires parentheses either around the function expression or around the whole function plus function-call parentheses combination: `(function () { return 10; })()` or `(function () { return 10; }())`. Parentheses ensure that `function () {}` is interpreted as a function expression rather than a function declaration. The equivalent of the second construction, `(function () return 10 end())`, is invalid in Lua. In JavaScript but not Lua, you can provide a name in function expressions, and the name will be shown in stack traces in case of an error: `(function f() { return 10; })()` or `(function f() { return 10; }())`.

Answer (score 3):

As a warning, DO NOT FORGET to delimit the last statement with a `;` before throwing an IIFE in. I kept getting a bunch of stupid errors saying that a table value (or another non-function) was getting called, when it turns out that Lua was assuming that `(function ... end)()` were parentheses for calling a statement a few lines above.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
split = require('string_methods/split')

(function()
    print('hi')
    return 1 
end)()
```

This returns the error:

```
lua: split-test.lua:2: attempt to call a table value
stack traceback:
    split-test.lua:2: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

This no longer happens after explicitly delimiting the line before the IIFE with a semicolon.

```
split = require('string_methods/split');

(function()
    print('hi')
    return 1 
end)()
```

Output:

```
hi
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that knowledge. Really useful bit of knowledge to randomly stumble upon! In your specific case, the issue is that `require()` pulls in a table/function, and then Lua thinks the parenthesis for the IIFE after that "are the parameter for the function returned by `require()`". I suspect that the issue you found would only happen when the preceding statement is something that *can* take a parenthesis argument -- such as `require("foo")("bar")`.